# How to present a Scene when touching the screen?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skscene, sktransition

My Game is in the GameScene and Menu in my MainMenu Scene.

I put the following code in the overridden `touchesBegan` of the MainMenu Scene to present the GameScene:

```
   let reveal = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.5)
   let NextScene = GameScene(size: self.size)
   NextScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.aspectFill
   self.view?.presentScene(NextScene, transition:reveal)
```

But if I test it I get the following error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I just don't understand why because in the GameScene I have the follow code in the GameOver function which works perfectly fine:

```
    let reveal = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.5)
    let MainMenuScene = MainMenu(size: self.size)
    MainMenuScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.aspectFill
    self.view?.presentScene(MainMenuScene, transition:reveal)
```

They are the exact same but only the one in the GameOver Function works, why?

Comment: It would helpful to see the line where you are doing a hard unwrapping of a nil value.

Comment: How do i find the line? it doesn't show me a red warning sign or something

Comment: When it crashes on EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION Xcode should display the offending line in red, at least if its in your code. You would also see the call stack in the left hand bar (Debug Navigator).

Comment: When it crashes it just goes to a different window which is called Thread 1, and then theres a message in the last line saying: Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1005c51fc). And i can't find any red line in my code after it crashes.

Comment: try to call these four lines using nested if like: if    let reveal = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.5){
if   let NextScene = GameScene(size: self.size){
   NextScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.aspectFill
   self.view?.presentScene(NextScene, transition:reveal)}} .. will prevent you to the crash.

Comment: Both if statements have a Error: "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not "SKTransition"" and  "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not "GameScene"". And if i put brackets like this: if (let reveal = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.5)){ theres also an Error

Comment: Are you sure that you spelled your class (scene) names correctly? Maybe you made a spelling error/typo somewhere. I would suspect that the mistake would be when you initially choose the name of the scene

Comment: Just put an execption breakpoint to see what line causes a crash. And be careful with forced unwrapping as well as forced downcasting.

Comment: I think there could be a forced assignment in your GameScene to `didMoveTo` method or inside this class..you should investigate there..

Comment: It seems like there's something wrong with: player = self.childNode(withName: "player") as! SKSpriteNode, but i don't know what.

Comment: any ideas what wrong with it?